# M3U8 Downloading with YT-DLP by passing data as a parameter

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, youtube-dl, m3u8, yt-dlp

i tried to send get request with data as a parameter:

```py
import requests

x=requests.get(
  'https://livepullsm.facecast.live/live/23331_sm_9cc3wn78.m3u8?txSecret=dc703b3b5c9e353c2538de0c518358d2&txTime=65BB30AD',
  data={'systoken': '43d0a1d8176ea2df98f14547ee5dee56'})

print(x.text)
```

it return this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:1706680207
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:3
#EXTINF:1.954,
23331_sm_9cc3wn78-1706680207.ts?txspiseq=106387013612687064120
#EXTINF:2.008,
23331_sm_9cc3wn78-1706680208.ts?txspiseq=106387013612687064120
#EXTINF:2.061,
23331_sm_9cc3wn78-1706680209.ts?txspiseq=106387013612687064120
```

taking those systoken as a params won't work, i tried this:

```py
requests.get('https://livepullsm.facecast.live/live/23331_sm_9cc3wn78.m3u8?txSecret=dc703b3b5c9e353c2538de0c518358d2&txTime=65BB30AD&systoken=43d0a1d8176ea2df98f14547ee5dee56')
```

and it return none.

The question is:
I'm trying to download the same url on `yt-dlp` but i don't really know how do i pass the `data`. i hope you can help me to find the way to do that.